# Installing a Particular Library Version

Tags: maven, chef-infra

Using vagrant-berkshelf with the Maven and Tomcat cookbooks, I can specify a major version to install.

Example: Maven  - 2 or 3
         Tomcat - 5 or 6

If I want to specify an exact version of a library (Maven 3.2.1), should I just use the Ark Cookbook to install the desired version?

Having limited DevOps experience, I'm used to making use of `yum` or `apt-get` to manage my libraries without specifying a particular version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Maven cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/maven/blob/master/recipes/default.rb) already uses ark. So you could just override the following node attributes:

```
node['maven']['version'] = 3
node['maven']['3']['version'] = '3.2.1'
node['maven']['3']['url'] = ???
node['maven']['3']['checksum'] = ???
```

The tomcat cookbook on the other hand does a package install, so you'd need to use ark or build a Deb/RPM package.

The only downside to using ark for tomcat is that you won't have service scripts to manage tomcat's stop/start/status. Some extra work would be needed.

## Update

The following is a vagrant project that installs Maven 3.2.1

```
├── Berksfile
└── Vagrantfile
```

### Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.require_plugin "vagrant-omnibus"
Vagrant.require_plugin "vagrant-berkshelf"
Vagrant.require_plugin "vagrant-chef-zero"

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  # Box config
  config.vm.box = "saucy64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/saucy/current/saucy-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"

  # Virtualbox config
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 4096]
  end

  # Networking config
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.10"

  # Plugin config
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
  config.chef_zero.enabled = true
  config.berkshelf.enabled = true

  # Chef config
  config.vm.provision :chef_client do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe "apt"
    chef.add_recipe "maven"

    chef.json = {
      'maven' => {
        'version' => 3,
        '3' => {
          'version' => '3.2.1',
          'url' => 'http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.2.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.1-bin.tar.gz',
          'checksum' => 'cdee2fd50b2b4e34e2d67d01ab2018b051542ee759c07354dd7aed6f4f71675c'

        }
      }
    }
  end
end
```

### Berksfile

```
site :opscode

cookbook 'apt'
cookbook 'maven'
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to specify `node['maven']['version'] = 3
node['maven']['3']['version'] = '3.2.1'` as JSON configuration for my Vagrantfile?

Comment: thank you, Mark. Lastly, is it possible to specify a destination for the installation of Maven? For example - how would I install Maven to `/opt/kevin`, i.e. M2_HOME would be that directory?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Yes... It's documented as one of the cookbook attributes, node['maven']['m2_home'] (see: http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/maven) and used in the code here: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/maven/blob/master/recipes/default.rb#L31